# What is the differences between instance specification and object

Tags: uml

In UML there are two related concepts:

1. instance specification
2. object

What is the differences between instance specification and object?

Comment: In UML models, instance specifications are elements that represent an instance in the modeled system. When you instantiate a classifier in a model, the instance specification that you create represents an entity in the modeled system at a point in time, similar to a snapshot of the entity. You can model changes to the entity over time by creating several instance specifications, one for each snapshot.

Comment: thank you @TheNewIdiot ! what about object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In most of the cases, think of instance and object are the same thing. If you really interested with the difference between them, then...
2. We need to firstly know the relationship between "class" and classifier, the former is concrete, the latter is abstract.

   UML2.5 / 11 Structured Classifiers / Classes
   *Class is the concrete realization of EncapsulatedClassifier and BehavioredClassifier. The purpose of a Class is to specify a classification of objects and to specify the Features that characterize the structure and behavior of those objects.*
3. I would say, an object is an instance of class; an InstanceSpecification is the instance of a classifier.
   Quoted from UML 2.5

   The InstanceSpecification may represent:
   *Classification of the instance by one or more Classifiers. If the only Classifier specified is abstract, then the InstanceSpecification only partially describes the instance.*
4. "object" is actually not an concept of UML, the InstanceSpecification is a more abstract concept and all its semantics applies to "object".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instance Specification is a concept used for modeling the internals of UML.

An user of UML should not worry about this. 
Implementors of CASE tools in the other hand are aware of this concept since they need it to make the sintatic rules of the language be applied in their tools.

Object is a concept that is more OO than UML itself. An object is an instance of a class.